How can I make dependencies in other folders resolve imports from the current build folder's node_modules?
I'm trying to convert two Angular repos and their two shared submodule dependencies into one monorepo. To prepare for this process, I've tried to hoist the shared dependencies out of one of the projects and into a parent directory.
i.e, from:
/[repo-root]
  tsconfig.json
  angular.json
  package.json
  /node_modules
  /src
    /dependency1
    /dependency2

to:
/[repo-root]
  /main-app
    tsconfig.json
    angular.json
    package.json
    /node_modules
  /dependency1
  /dependency2

I've added the following to my tsconfig.json to remap these imports:
paths:
{
  "@dependency1/*": ["../dependency1/*"],
  "@dependency2/*": ["../dependency2/*"],
}

This works fine for importing things from these folders, but then the files in dependency1 & 2 can't resolve the contents of node_modules. Is there a way to specify that even "external" dependencies should try to resolve their imports using this local context?
I'm aware that solutions like Nx exist that solve the broader dependency management problems for monorepo projects, but I'd like to minimize the change risk and perform that migration after the "get all the stuff in the same git repo" migration, if possible.

Have you tried adding the following path? "*": ["node_modules/*"],

@JSONDerulo This appears to allow resolution of the items in the node_modules folder, but also appears to break some packages (e.g. aws-amplify), and interferes with VSCode's language server.

from the typescript docs:
"resolution features that happen for node_modules package lookups, including package.json "exports" field support, do not take effect when a paths alias is matched."

A monorepo follows this structure
/repo
  /project1
  /project2
  /project-n
  /lib
  /package.json
  /node_modules
  /angular.json

Where the project folders are the different angular applications that are sharing dependencies.
Those dependencies can be in the form of third-party node_module packages or in-house libraries (/lib).
If the dependencies are in-house codes, then you should create an angular library and put the codes in it and just reference them in your application folders as you would reference any other code written in the application folders.
This is the command to add a library to your project.
ng generate library my-lib

You can find more info on Angular's website

As stated in my question, I'd like to avoid merging the dependencies of the two front-end projects until a later point in time. While this is definitely an approach for achieving an angular monorepo, it isn't a method to make dependencies in other folders resolve imports from the current build directory.

Are dependency1 and dependency2 angular applications or angular libraries? Are the dependencies that you are trying to avoid merging the node_modules or node_modules+angular_library?

They're folders full of typescript files. If you expect an "angular library" to have more structure than that, then this is not that.
I'm trying to avoid merging the NPM dependencies of main-app and some-other-app, which will be merged in later.

From what I understand your problem is that you have two ng apps with the same in-house ts dependencies, and you want to set it up such that the two projects while being separate ng workspaces share the same in-house ts dependencies. If so, then you should create an ng library, put your in-house deps there, deploy it privately on npm, and import it in your projects. If you don't want to deploy to npm, you have to modify your library's build script to output the built code to the node_modules of your separate apps, but that will be an issue if you run an automated CD.
